# Seeking photos from HMS Glendower & Royal Arthur?

Tags: world-war-2, navy, photo

My grandfather served in HMS Royal Arthur from 1939-1940 as an instructor, before he moved to HMS Glendower. He was a Petty Officer Gunner. Kelleher was his name, and he was an irishman by birth.

Where might I be able to find more information about either Royal Arthur or Glendower?

I am hoping to uncover photos of the personnel and life therein.

Comment: Hello -- this is a Q&A site not a forum so thie question doesn't really fit here. You could try editing it to fit ourguidelines at https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic and https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask if you have specific question syou need to address about your grandfather but asking for photos doesn't belong here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not asking for an answer to a question

Comment: Can we salvage this by editing it to make it more generally useful and more in-line with the site guidelines -- how to find websites and background information about WWII ships, etc?

Comment: Sounds like a great idea @JanMurphy

Answer (score 2):

There  is a  chapter with   photos on  both HMS  Royal  Arthur  and  HMS  Glendower  in  ***[The  Reminiscences  of a  Radar   Plotter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1905999240)***  by  John  Barford  Lindop  (  Amazon  Books )   where all,  well  some,  will  be  revealed.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format which is quite different from bulletin boards, discussion forums and other Q&A sites you may be used to.  I am assuming from your user name that you are the author of this book.

Comment: Hi,Yes,  I  am  the  author